# MD5 - Method is undefined for type String

Tags: java

I have a method which takes a String as an argument and returns the MD5 value of the String as a String. However, when I use the method I get "Th method md5() is undefined for type String". I'm probably just too tired too see an error I made, could you help me?

```
public static String md5(String s) {
        try {
            MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            m.reset();
            m.update(s.getBytes());
            byte[] digest = m.digest();
            BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, digest);
            return bigInt.toString(16);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

public void hashing() {
    int counter = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<slovo.length(); i++) {
        if (slovo.charAt(i)=='_') {
            sb.append(characters.charAt(array[counter]));
            counter++;
        }else {
            sb.append(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    if (sb.toString().md5()==hash) { //this is the line which is producing the error

    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: The error is that `String` has no `md5()` method. Also, you have to compare strings with `equals()` not `==`

Answer (score 2):

A String object does not have the method md5(), and md5 takes in a single argument.
Did you mean `md5(sb.toString())` ?

Comment: Yeah, just noticed it. Sleep deprivation is making it's mark. Thanks!